# Can I make transient / persist an entire data structure?

Tags: clojure

From what I can tell from the [Clojure docs page for transient](http://clojure.org/transients), calling `transient` and `persistent!` on a data structure only acts on that collection object (vector, hash-map or hash-set).

If I have a tree of objects, is there a way to recursively take a transient copy of the entire structure? And then to turn the whole structure back?

Comment: You'll probably have to roll your own with `clojure.walk/postwalk`.

Comment: @Alex if you post this as an answer I will totally vote for it

Comment: @ArthurUlfeldt turns out clojure.walk doesn't work with transients. So you're *really* going to have to roll your own.

Answer (score 0):

It seems likely as @Alex has said that you'll need to roll your own function that walks the data structure. Also note that there is no `assoc-in!` parallel to `assoc-in` which suggests you may end up rolling your own version of that as well if you want to `assoc-in` to the nested data structure.